# thread dump of a stand-alone java app

Tags: java

I have a stand-alone java app running on linux + Java 6, which seems to be stuck (no logs being generated)
How can i take thread dump of this, without using any other tool (eg. jstack)

Tried below commands, but they are not doing anything

```
kill -3 <pid>
kill -QUIT <pid>
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Ok. Got it. "Ctrl + \" gives me the dump.

Comment: Please convert your comment to an answer and self-accept it.

Comment: `kill -3` should also work. The only time this doesn't work is when you can't see the console.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Sorry, didn't get you. By console you mean terminal ? If yes, then I was using terminal only.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz. Sure, will do it after 8hr :)

Comment: You have to type the command in a shell prompt, if that is what you mean. i.e. another window. You can't type it in as input to the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java VisualVM (included in every JDK's bin directory) and connect through JMX. Just add

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=PORT
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

to your JVM startup parameters (at remote host) and enable authentication.

Then start VisualVM (at your client) and add a connection.

See here: http://visualvm.java.net/docindex.html

Comment: Working on a remote server, and it doesn't have VisualVM.

Comment: At your remote server you just have to enable jmx support, shown above. Isn't your client using an xserver?

Answer (score 0):

Get the pid from the `jps` command (although not necessary).

Did you try with root privileges? If the java process was initiated with root (or daemon) privileges you must take this into account.

```
# kill -3 <pid>
$ sudo kill -QUIT <pid>
```

You can also see the threads in the `top` output by pressing `H` (not `h`).

Then if you identify the stuck you can grab the pid, make hexadecimal and then with the `jstack` see the stack trace.

Regards.

Comment: What about that `kill -9` (SIGKILL)? That will unconditionally kill the process.

Comment: @Christian.K I think he wants a thread dump rather than just kill the process

Comment: That was my point. Your second line `sudo kill -9 <pid>` _does_ kill the process.